# transpose row to column in python

Tags: python, shell, csv, numpy, transpose

I am a newbie in python and I would like to transpose a CSV-formated file. The file I have is structured like this:

```
Country;Class;Number
UK;1;50
Germany;2;30
France;3;50
France;1;20
```

I need to transpose the class variable into columns, i.e.

```
          class1 class2

country      Number Number
```

Is it possible to do that in Shell or in Python?

I know that it's possible to transpose a matrix completely with `zip()` in Python but I just want to transpose the `class`-column. Is it possible to do that in Python or in a shellscript?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Could you please clarify the example? Please illustrate what the structure currently is (which you seem to have done) and the output that you want (which is currently unclear).

Answer (score 1):

You want to pivot, not transpose the data:

```
import pandas
from io import StringIO # python 3
# from StringIO import StringIO # python 2

datafile = StringIO("""\
Country;Class;Number
UK;1;50
Germany;2;30
France;3;50
France;1;20
""")
df = pandas.read_csv(datafile, sep=';')
print(df.pivot(index='Country', columns='Class', values='Number'))

Class     1   2   3
Country            
France   20 NaN  50
Germany NaN  30 NaN
UK       50 NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
    # make a dict of empty lists, to contain our values
    transposed = {k:[] for k in reader.fieldnames}  # could use defaultdict here
    for row in reader:
        for k, v in row.items():
            transposed[k].append(v)
print(transposed)
```

This will give you a dictionary which looks like this:

```
{
    'Country': ['UK', 'Germany', 'France', 'France'],
    'Class': ['1', '2', '3', '1'],
    'Number': ['50', '30', '50', '20']
}
```

**Bonus:** You could also use a `collections.defaultdict` instead of using a dictionary comprehension to set up your `transposed`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
transposed = defaultdict(list)
```